# Microsoft JScript runtime error: FindControl requires that controls have unique IDs

Tags: asp.net

I'm programmatically adding a row to a System.Web.UI.WebControls.Table inside an UpdatePanel.  I then add cells to the row and controls to the cells.

Once the controls have been added I get Microsoft JScript runtime error:

"Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Multiple controls with the same ID 'txtValue' were found.  FindControl requires that controls have unique IDs."

Because the controls are in seperate rows, should then not get their own client IDs, making them unique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table doesn't quite work like that.  Each row is not a container in the same way it would be in say a GridView.  Why would you not simply give them unique names?

Comment: I'm dynamically building rows with text boxes.  When the user clicks a submit button, I need to iterate through all rows and finx specific text boxes, so I was hoping to use FindControl, and pass a specific id, but I suppose I can generate a unique id and figure out what id to look for before I call FindControl

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure but try add the control to the page control collection too

```
this.Controls.Add( txtValue );
```

Comment: You can't add the same control to multiple parents.